# When do lists, collections etc throw a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Java?

Tags: java

The following code uses a simple list and displays elements contained in the list through a foreach loop and again through a while loop.

```
final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {           
        List<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");

        for(Object o:list)
        {
            System.out.printf("\n"+o);
        }

        Iterator<String>listIterator=list.iterator();

        //list.add("E");   If uncommented, throws an exception.
        //list.add("F");

        while(listIterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.printf("\n"+listIterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

---

When the commented two lines above the while loop are uncommented, it throws an exception `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. If those commented lines are placed above this line `Iterator<String>listIterator=list.iterator();`, it works well.  Such exceptions are very common while handling entities in **EJBs**. Why does this happen? How can it be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Instead of using:

```
Iterator<String>listIterator=list.iterator();
```

use:

```
ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator();
```

This iterator provides an `add()` method for you to use. Note in the JavaDoc how it works though as it may not provide exactly what you need - it doesn't add to the end of the list but rather a location relative to the `ListIterator`'s position.

Comment: +1 for quoting the relevant doc, but I don't think the suggestion to use `ListIterator` is a great one. At least, it needs more explanation: if the OP followed your suggestion to the letter, `"E"` and `"F"` would get inserted at the beginning of the list instead of appended to the end.

Comment: @ruakh - I agree and was editing to add that when you posted your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Each collection maintains a variable called modCount. This variable keeps a track of the number of times collection has been modified. 
Find below the javadoc of mdcount from AbstractList

```
/**
* The number of times this list has been <i>structurally modified</i>.
* Structural modifications are those that change the size of the
 * list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in
 * progress may yield incorrect results.
 *
 * <p>This field is used by the iterator and list iterator implementation
 * returned by the {@code iterator} and {@code listIterator} methods.
 * If the value of this field changes unexpectedly, the iterator (or list
 * iterator) will throw a {@code ConcurrentModificationException} in
 * response to the {@code next}, {@code remove}, {@code previous},
 * {@code set} or {@code add} operations.  This provides
 * <i>fail-fast</i> behavior, rather than non-deterministic behavior in
 * the face of concurrent modification during iteration.
 *
 * <p><b>Use of this field by subclasses is optional.</b> If a subclass
 * wishes to provide fail-fast iterators (and list iterators), then it
 * merely has to increment this field in its {@code add(int, E)} and
 * {@code remove(int)} methods (and any other methods that it overrides
 * that result in structural modifications to the list).  A single call to
 * {@code add(int, E)} or {@code remove(int)} must add no more than
 * one to this field, or the iterators (and list iterators) will throw
 * bogus {@code ConcurrentModificationExceptions}.  If an implementation
 * does not wish to provide fail-fast iterators, this field may be
 * ignored.
 */
protected transient int modCount = 0;
```

When iterator is made, a local copy of modCount is kept and this is checked before returning a new object. If there has been a change, Concurrent modification exception is thrown.

The exception can be avoided by not doing any operations on the collection while it is being iterated. Only remove is permitted and that should also be routed through the iterator i.e. Iterator#remove