# How to effectively  add, set and remove elements from List, Collection etc in Java?

Tags: java, list

Following is the errorneous code in Java.

```
package wrapper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

final public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String... args) 
    {
        List<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");

        Iterator<String>it=list.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String item=it.next();

            if(item.equals("B"))
            {
                list.remove(item);
            }
            System.out.println(item);
        }


        ListIterator<String>listIterator=list.listIterator();

        listIterator.set("D");       //Throws java.lang.IllegalStateException
        listIterator.add("D");

        System.out.print("\n\n");
        for(Object o:list)
        {
            System.out.println(o);
            if(o.equals("C"))
            {
                listIterator.remove();    //Throws java.lang.IllegalStateException
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

While handling entities in **EJBs** or otherwise, the use of `List`, `Collection`, `Set` etc is very common. Sometime while modifying them after the respective iterators have been created, they throw `java.lang.CurrentModificationException` that is very critical to avoid.

---

In the above code, I can't add or remove elements after creating the `Iterator it`. Doing so throws `java.lang.CurrentModificationException`. How to avoid it effectively?

---

Next I have used `ListIterator<String>` named **listIterator** which throws respective exceptions as can be shown in the above code in comments. How can we avoid them and add & set elements effectively using the add() and set() methods respectively?

---

Also, adding elements to the `listIterator` through the statement `listIterator.add("D");` displays the elements on top of the list. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do lists, collections etc throw a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191087/when-do-lists-collections-etc-throw-a-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception) - I'm not sure what more you're looking for. The answers to your previous question and the javadocs pretty much cover why your code does that, and no, you can't avoid it.

Comment: JavaDoc is clear: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html. You can use `remove()` or `set()` only if you did a `next()` first. You cannot remove elements from normal `Iterator`. The docs are clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a ConcurrentModificationException because you're modifying the underlying collection while trying to iterate over it. You can't call `remove` on `list` inside a loop where you're using an iterator on `list`.

The Iterator interface, however, provides an optional `remove` method that can be used to remove an item from the list you're iterating over. Calling `it.remove();` inside your loop will remove the last element returned from the iterator.

The same applies for the ListIterator.

As for why the add method puts things on "top of the list", check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29). What is happening is that the new element is being put into the underlying list directly in front of the element that would be returned on the next call to `next`. So on your next iteration through the loop, when you call `next` you will get the element you just inserted.